# How does Peer to Peer model works in online games?

Tags: networking, game-engine, p2p

as mentioned in the title above. I know how client/server model actually works by sending and receiving game states from server to clients(easy to understand.) but on P2P archicture if each "peer" controlls their own games states by sending/receiving a simulation of players inputs, then *How does each peer can keep in sync when taking a network latency into account?* Say if there were 4 players located in the same world area behaving simultenously, will each peer *receive the same actions experiencing the same network latency as the laggy player? Or it's independent?* assuming they live far away from each other?

Comment: *It depends.* A lot. On the game, the network model, the necessities and the tradeoffs that are acceptable to the game.

Comment: Yeah that's relevant too. But what i'm trying to say is if someone was lagging in your screen, will this affect the other players too? I hope that not the case... Otherwise the game will not work probably xD

Comment: Again: it depends. In a one-on-one fighting game (e.g. Mortal Kombat), being 100% in sync is crucial to the game, so lags must cause pauses of some kind. In an open-ended space flight simulation 100% synchronisation is probably not as important most of the time and it's probably acceptable to have only rough synchronisation for the most part. There is no one answer, each game has to make its own decisions.

Comment: Yeah of course thanks for reminding me that. plenty of games use that "100% Synchronization" like Most fighting games where each millisecond count and to make battles more fair. Though other games like GTA V and some Racing games doesn't use that method and everything appears in your screen is more or less a "Simulation" to what everyone did at that time.  Anyways.. Thank you so much for taking your time answering my questions. Really appreciated! :)

Comment: Hey deceze. Can i ask or maybe discuss with you something about a "Listen Server" if you have some knowledge about it? :)